# StringContent Issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, slack-api

Don't really get what's wrong with this chunk of code, been doing so many StringContent POST actions but this is the first occurrence...

This chunk of code is just made to POST data to Slack directly with HttpClient. The code will run up till the PostAsync method, by which would then crash, producing no exception logs. The only information I have is when I step debug to .PostAsync, and utilise the current variables I have at that point of time to retrieve the error StringContent has. Is there any structure by which I require to follow in order to make StringContent a type?

```
error CS0119: 'StringContent' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

[image]

The code for the entire class is here:

```
namespace XXXXXXXXX
{
    public class SlackClient : ISlackClient
    {
        private readonly string _urlWithAccessToken;
        private readonly Uri _uri;
        private readonly Encoding _encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        public SlackClient(string urlWithAccessToken)
        {
            _urlWithAccessToken = urlWithAccessToken;
            _uri = new Uri(urlWithAccessToken);
        }

        public async Task TestPostMessageAsync()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            await client.PostAsync(_urlWithAccessToken, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new BasicPayload() {
                Text = "Hello World, this is from .NET Core"
            }), _encoding, "application/json"));
        }

        //Post a message using simple strings  
        public async Task PostMessageAsync(string text, string username = null, string channel = null)
        {
            Payload payload = new Payload()
            {
                Channel = channel,
                Username = username,
                Text = text
            };

            await PostMessageAsync(payload);
        }

        //Post a message using a Payload object  
        public async Task PostMessageAsync(Payload payload)
        {
            try {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                //string postBodyStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                // var stringContent = new StringContent(postBodyStr);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(_urlWithAccessToken, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), _encoding));

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                //The response text is usually "ok"  
                //string responseText = _encoding.GetString(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine("[SlackClient] POST to Webhook failed: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ISlackClient only contains the methods for the inheriting class to comply with, there's really nothing much. The Payload object contains the format of which Slack has offered for its Webhooks and has JsonProperty binded to every property.

Controller that executes the SlackClient:

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly RavenLogger _rLogger;
        private readonly SlackClient _slackLogger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
          UserManager<User> userManager,
          SignInManager<User> signInManager,
          IRavenClient _ravenClient)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _rLogger = new RavenLogger("HomeController", _ravenClient, LogLevel.Information);
            _slackLogger = new SlackClient(ApplicationSettings.GetString("Slack/CoreLoggingWebHook"));
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            // Log to Sentry
            //_rLogger.LogInformation(
            //(int) LogEnum.VIEWINDEX, null, $"{HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress} Viewed Index");
            //await new SlackClient(ApplicationSettings.GetString("Slack/CoreLoggingWebHook")).PostMessageAsync("[GET Home/Index] Called by " + HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
                    //, "HomeController", "#core-log");
            await _slackLogger.TestPostMessageAsync();

            if (user != null)
            {
                return View(new IndexViewModel
                {
                    DisplayName = user.FirstName,
                    HasPassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user),
                    PhoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user),
                    TwoFactor = await _userManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user),
                    Logins = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user),
                    BrowserRemembered = await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user),
                    IsDriver = user.DriverId > 0
                });
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: And how is the above code being called? provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi via an API Controller, will include that code as well